# Prove subspace of finite dimensional vector space is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Prove that any subspace, *W*, of a finite-dimensional vector space *V* must also be finite dimensional.

Comment: Suppose for sake of contradiction that *W* isn't finite dimensional. That will probably contradict *V* being finite dimensional.

Comment: I'd rather not without first seeing what you've done.  Mind showing us your work and where you got stuck?

Comment: @Neal Well my professor gave a hint saying we can use the Plus-minus theorem to prove this but i'm not sure how to go about proving this using plus-minus theorem.

Comment: You don't have to use the plus-minus theorem, but if you really want to, try to think of a set of vectors to apply the "plus" or the "minus" to yield a contradiction with *W* being finite dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a basis $\beta$ of $W$, then $\beta$ is linearly independent in $V$ so you can extend $\beta$ to $\gamma$ a basis of $V$, so $\gamma$ must be finite, by hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $n=\dim\ V$. What is the maximum size of any linearly independent subset of $V$?