# Suppose that $V$ is a vector space, and $W$ is a subspace of $V$. If $V$ is finite dimensional, then prove $W$ too must be finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, vectors, infinity

> Suppose that $V$ is a vector space, and $W$ is a subspace of $V$. If
>   $V$ is finite dimensional, then prove $W$ too must be finite dimensional.

It seems intuitively obvious that the dimension of $W$ must be less than or equal to that of $V$, but I am uncertain of how specifically to show this to be true analytically.

This question has been asked before ([seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240230/prove-subspace-of-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-finite-dimensional)). However, there is not a great degree of explanation in the given answers. The answer which labels itself as a hint is most similar to my thoughts towards an approach to proving this particular theorem.

I was thinking that if $\exists n\in\mathbb{R}:n=\text{dim}(V) \implies \exists B = \{\vec{v}_1,...,\vec{v}_n\}$, a basis for $V$, with $n$ vectors $\vec{v}_1, ..., \vec{v}_1 \in V$. Since $W$ is a subspace of $V \implies \beta$, a basis for $W$, which has $m$ vectors in it can be constructed by removing $k\in\mathbb{R}$ vectors from $B$ such that $B\setminus\{\vec{v}_i,...,\vec{v}_j\}=\beta$ where $\vec{v}_i,...,\vec{v}_j$ are those $k$ vectors. This means a basis for $W$ has $m=n-k$ vectors in it, and by the definition of bases $\implies \text{dim}(W)=m$, and since $n-k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n-k=m \implies m\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $W$ is finite. $\square$

It seems like there may be some fault with this argument, though.

Comment: Do you mean finite dimensional or literally finite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove subspace of finite dimensional vector space is finite dimensional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240230/prove-subspace-of-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-finite-dimensional)

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Did you actually take the time to read what I wrote? I addressed that question specifically. It did not answer my question, and **furthermore**, my question is a proof verification.

Comment: @AdamHughes Finite dimensional, apologies.

Comment: It is an autocomment. Keep calm, dude.

Comment: If anything, the other question should be closed as a duplicate since that one is terribly written and this post and solutions cover it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof doesn't work : for example taking the canonical basis $\mathscr{C}=\big((1,0),(0,1)\big)$ of $V=\mathbb{R}^2,$ you can't extract from $\mathscr{C}$ a correct basis of $W=vect(1,1).$ The good argument would be to say that if $V$ is of dimension $n$ and if $W$ was not a finite-dimensional space, then you can take from $W$ an independant family of $n+1$ vectors which would always be independant in $V,$ leading you to a contradiction.

Comment: I see why my argument fails, but I don't understand the proof you've presented. I don't know what you mean by "free family".

Comment: Perhaps it is my vocabulary : does independant family sounds better ?

Comment: Do you mean a set of independent vectors? Why would it be a contradiction to say that you could have an $n+1$ set of linearly independent vectors from $W$?

Comment: Because you know that if a vectorial space is of dimension $n,$ then : $(i)$ a set of $n+1$ vectors or more can't be independant, $(ii)$ a set of $n-1$ vectors or less can't be generator. Here $(i)$ give the contradiction.

Comment: Oh, right, because a subset is composed only of vectors in the parent space so the number of components in a vector which are nonzero for a subspace vector can only be $n$ or less, right? This would mean that an independent set of vectors cold hold no more than $n$ independent vectors, which leads to the contradiction, right?

Comment: It is exactly that !

Answer (score 0):

The usual argument is the following: take a basis $B=\{w_i:i\in I\}$ of $W$. This can always be extended to a basis $B'$ of $V$, since $B$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$. Now $B'$ is assumed to be finite, and so indeed $B$ is finite, and $$\dim V=|B'|\geqslant |B|=\dim W$$

Comment: Is $I$ the set of integers such that $1 \leq i \leq n$? I'm not familiar with $I$.

Something about this argument seems to presuppose the result. I'm not saying it's wrong, by any means, but some ignorance of my own disallows me to understand the argument.

I know that the Plus-Minus Theorem states:

For $S$ is a linearly independent set, and $v$ a vector in $V$ with $v$ outside the $\text{span}(S)$, then
the set $S\cup\{v\}$ that results from inserting $v$ into $S$ is still linearly independent.

But I guess I wonder what if $W$ a subset of $V$ is of greater dimension than $V$?

Comment: @MSL No, $I$ is *some* indexing set for the basis of $W$. The argument shows it must be finite. The "plus minus theorem" you call is the core of the argument essentially, but the full argument needs Zorn's lemma.  Without any air of personal self promotion, I encourage you to read [this](https://specksofmath.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/dependence-relations-a-case-a-good-abstraction/) blog post of mine.

Comment: @MSL The "plus minus theorem" you state is a consequence of the more refined *replacement axiom* of Steinitz: if $v$ is in the span of $S$ but not in the span of $S-w$ for some $w\in S$; then in fact $w$ is in the span of $(S-w)\cup v$.

Comment: Note that the proof above shows $W$ cannot be a subspace of greater dimension than $V$, of course!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Could you please clarify your previous comment?  Is it the case that "every subspace of a finite-dimensional space is finite-dimensional" is equivalent to Zorn's Lemma?  Thanks.

Comment: @David No. If $R$ is a noetherian ring and $M$ an $R$-module that is finitely generated then it is automatically noetherian, so all its submodules are finitely generated. Since fields are noetherian, and any finite dimensional vector space is finitely generated, all its subspaces are finitely generated. It suffices one shows that if $V$ is any vector space generated by finitely many vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_l$; there is a subset that is a basis. This doesn't need Zorn's lemma.